# Como adicionar uma classe em um <li> quando a pessoa estiver na página do link acessado?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou criando um site utilizando `PHP` com `includes` para uma melhor manutenção, porém estou tendo um problema.

Se eu utilizasse somente `HTML` esse problema não estaria ocorrendo, pois como estou utilizando `includes` para **puxar o menu**, não consigo adicionar uma classe em todas as páginas.

Tenho um menu que utiliza um código como esse:

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
     <li>
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Agora vamos supor que eu esteja na página `index.php` então tem que ser adicionado uma classe ao `<li>` **Início**.

Para um melhor entendimento, veja:

#### Como está se eu estiver na página index.php (*errado*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Como tem que ficar se eu estiver na página index.php (**certo**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Exemplo:

> Se a pessoa estiver na página `index.php` tem que ser adicionado a classe (**ativo**) no  `<li>` **Início**.
>
> Se a pessoa estiver na página `sobre.php` tem que ser adicionado a classe (**ativo**) no `<li>` **Sobre** e assim em diante.

No caso tem que ser adicionado uma classe, ficando assim, ex:

```
<li class="ativo">
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
</li>
```

---

Obs: Isso me lembrou bastante a função **`permalink`** do Wordpress.

> Um exemplo é o site WP Total: http://www.wptotal.com/

Quando eu entro no site, o nome `Início` no menu fica laranja.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu acessar a página sobre, o nome **Sobre** no menu fica laranja.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em todos os .php tens o menu(repetido)?

Comment: Sim @JorgeB eu utilizo includes em todas as páginas para puxar o arquivo `menu.php` contendo o código do menu dentro.

Comment: Pode ser em jQuery?

Comment: Olá @MarceloAymone obrigado por tentar ajudar, mas acredito que via Javascript não seja a melhor solução, pois via PHP é mais fácil porque a página já é renderizada, via Js precisa esperar o carregamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `menu.php` é só fazeres:

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
     <li <?php if($verifica['index']==true) echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
     </li>
     <li <?php if($verifica['sobre']==true) echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a>
     </li>
     <li <?php if($verifica['contacto']==true) echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

E antes do `include` do `menu.php` tens de por a `true` a que queres e as outras a `false`:

Exemplo no `sobre.php`:

```
$verifica['index']=false;
$verifica['sobre']=true;
$verifica['cintacto']=false;
include 'menu.php';
```

---

**NOTA:**

Mas eu faria de outra forma com `$_GET`. Punha tudo o que fosse menus, *header*, *footer*, etc no `index.php` e depois incluía as outras páginas nesse `index.php` através de um `www.meudominio.pt/index.php?pagina=sobre`.

Depois era só fazer o `$_GET['pagina']` no `index.php` e fazer um `switch`:

**index.php:**

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
     <li <?php if($_GET['pagina']=="inicio") echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
     </li>
     <li <?php if($_GET['pagina']=="sobre") echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a>
     </li>
     <li <?php if($_GET['pagina']=="contato") echo "class='active'" ?> >
         <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
     </li>
</ul>

<?php
    switch($_GET['pagina']){
         case "inicio":
              //não faz nada
              break;

         case "sobre":
              include 'sobre.php';
              break;

         case "contato":
              include 'contato.php';
              break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: No menu onde tem **Produtos** eu criei `$verifica['produtos']` e onde tem **Link 2** eu criei `$verifica['link2']` assim funciona 100%!

Comment: Ainda bem que te ajudou em tudo :)

Comment: Vou estudar esse seu segundo exemplo utilizando `GET`, um amigo meu utiliza desta forma, porém nunca pensei em testa-la. O único problema é as URLs que atrapalha o SEO, mas nada que um `.htaccess` criando URLs amigáveis não ajeite.

Comment: E como faço a parte do Título da página no 2° exemplo? O 1° é muito fácil, já o 2° é mais complicado.

Answer (score 1):

acho que algo assim é mais pratico:

```
<?php
$pagina_atual = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'index.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="index.php">Início</a>
     </li>
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'sobre.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a>
     </li>
     <li<?php echo ($pagina_atual == 'contato.php' ? ' class="ativo"' : ''); ?>>
         <a href="contato.php">Contato</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Olá @Jader obrigado pela sua dica.